# Virtualenv changes user and code is not run

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, debian, virtualenv

On a Rapsberry PI Zero, I'm executing the below code in a python script in order to activate the virtual environment (virtualenv):

```
os.system('/bin/bash --rcfile /home/pi/project/venv/bin/activate')
```

It's works and the virtualenv venv is activated.
However the user is also changed from pi to root

**Why is the user changed and how I can prevent this?**

Also the code that is executed after the activation is not executed:

```
subprocess.run('pip install -r /home/pi/project/requirements.txt', shell=True)
```

**Why is the code not executed after activating the virtual environment and how can I install the packaged from the requirements file?**

*Code:*

```
    def create_activate_virtualenv(self):
    while True:
        env = str(input('Choose environment: dev(elopment) or prod(uction): '))
        if env == 'dev':
            print('<i>: Creating development environment.')
            subprocess.run('virtualenv /home/pi/project/venv-dev', shell=True)
            print('<i>: Activate development environment.')
            os.system('/bin/bash --rcfile /home/pi/project/venv-dev/bin/activate')
            subprocess.run('pip install -r /home/pi/project/requirements.txt', shell=True)
            break
        elif env == 'prod':
            print('<i>: Creating production environment.')
            subprocess.run('virtualenv /home/pi/project/venv-prod', shell=True)
            print('<i>: Activate production environment.')
            os.system('/bin/bash --rcfile /home/pi/project/venv-prod/bin/activate')
            subprocess.run('pip install -r /home/pi/project/requirements.txt', shell=True)
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: none of what you have should work, the activate script isn't something you can run, the pip install command will always run as your user and whatever virtualenv (or not) is activated by the current process

Comment: well, it does work until the virtual environment is activated, after that the code (``subprocess.run('pip install -r /home/pi/project/requirements.txt', shell=True)``) below the activation is not executed

Comment: running an activation script in a subprocess sets the variables *only for that subprocess*, once that ends you're back to the parent process with the same state as before -- there isn't a way to modify the parent's variables from a subprocess